# Add custom location button in right bottom corner like in GoogleMaps

Tags: android, android-button, osmdroid

What is the best way to add a button to the bottom right corner in my app with the maps, and change this button in different states like in GoogleMaps? I am using OSMDroid and need add custom button, not default.

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking you may need to use a RelativeLayout and put inside both the view, used by OSMDroid library (the code of which you may add in your question), and the custom button view. For a more detailed answer, pls give more details and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this layout and it get you what you are looking for

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment

            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewFlagPassenger"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/marker" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_passenger_current_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/location_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```